# Can single HL7 file contain multiple messages or just one?

Tags: hl7

I am trying to read & parse HL7 messages and have a question about how they're physically stored in a file.

Can a file contain multiple HL7 messages or will a file only contain single message?

Answer (score 1):

HL7 message files have mostly the extension *.hl7.

There are the **FHS** (file header), **FTS** (file trailer) and **BHS** (batch header), **BTS** (batch trailer) segments to envelope multiple HL7-messages in one message file.

I recommend to search for "hl7 fhs bhs" in Google.

from [HL7eu 2.3.6 HL7 Batch Protocol](http://www.hl7.eu/HL7v2x/v21/std21/KAP2.html#Heading45)

> ```
> [FHS] (file header segment)
>   { [BHS] (batch header segment)
>    { MSH (one or more HL7 messages)
>      ....
>      ....
>      ....
>     }
>    [BTS] (batch trailer segment)
>   }
>   [FTS] (file trailer segment)
> ```

Comment: May be I am not understanding this correctly but the link points to Oracle; not sure if this is their private implementation. I also had a look at [FHS Segment](https://hl7-definition.caristix.com/v2/HL7v2.2/Segments/FHS) discovered in google search you recommended; that does not look like what OP is asking for. Can you please point out something in HL7 Specifications that mentions about "file header" for HL7 message?

Comment: I do not have actual access to the official documents containing HL7 protocol. But I guess you will find the batch protocol sections in all HL7 versions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a concept in HL7 protocol as "File".

- **You** choose whether to store the message in file or save it in database or elsewhere.
- **You** create a file if you need.
- **You** choose its extension as ".hl7" or ".txt" or else.
- **You** choose whether there should be single message in a file or multiple.

HL7 message when transferred on socket needs to be enclosed in MLLP blocks. You can learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56250840/5779732) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63937061/5779732). Here, of-course it matters that you enclose **each** message separately in MLLP block.

Note that, even though you store the message in file, there is no "file header". So, to summarize it all -- "Its up to you".

---

I was not aware about `FHS` (file header) and `BHS` (batch header) feature ([2.3.6 HL7 Batch Protocol](http://www.hl7.eu/HL7v2x/v21/std21/KAP2.html#Heading45)) in HL7. I learned it from [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72458533/5779732) from @sqlab on this question.
Yes; it is a feature for batching the messages.
But I still do not think the `FHS` and `BHS` is "file header" the way we have header for JPEG or many other file types where we can read just header and validate file type.
If there is no `FHS` segment in message file, we cannot say it is not a HL7 message.
Not sure though, one may have multiple "batches" in single file.
IMO, this more behaves like "batching the messages" than a "file header".

About extension ".hl7"; yes, many organizations use this extension commonly for HL7 files.
But it is not **standard** or mandatory or forced per say (not mentioned in Specifications).
Just making the extension ".txt" does not make it invalid HL7 file; though some third party applications may not work with it, but that is different problem.